# Why the following C++ code gives this output?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to learn `Operator Overloading` in c++.I am addding two matrices using `Operator Overloading` concept.
I am using the statement `t3=t1+t2;` to call the overloaded method.

But the o/p is not as expected.The o/p matrix is coming out same as the second matrix.I can't understand why.

Here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int m,n;
class test
{
int a[][10];
public:

void get()
{
    cout<<"enter matrix elements"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
void print()
{
    cout<<"matrix is as follows "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

test operator + (test t2)
{
    test temp;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        temp.a[i][j]=a[i][j]+t2.a[i][j];
    }
    }
    return temp;
}
};
int main()
{
    cout<<"enter value of m and n"<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    cin>>n;
    test t1;
    t1.get();
    test t2;
    t2.get();
    t1.print();
    t2.print();

    test t3;
    t3=t1+t2;
    t3.print();
    return 0;
}
```

The o/p is---

```
G:\>a.exe
enter value of m and n
2
2
enter matrix elements
1
1
1
1
enter matrix elements
2
2
2
2
matrix is as follows
2       2
2       2
matrix is as follows
2       2
2       2
third matrix is as follows
2       2
2       2
```

Comment: If your compiler *did not* warn you about the `int a[][10];` flexible array member being used in a C++ program, I suggest you crank up your compiler warnings.

Comment: You are copying `test` objects in many place with no copy constructor operator...

Comment: since only column length is necessary,that's why i am specifying only column length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a[][10];
```

that's not allocating a proper array.  I believe that makes an array of size a[1][10], which you later access out of bounds when you say

```
cin>>a[i][j];
```

and

```
cout<<a[i][j]<<"\t";
```

with `i > 0`;

You should probably use a std::vector of std::vector's or otherwise you'll need to allocate dynamic memory yourself using new/delete.  You cannot create a dynamically sized array on the stack in c++.

You can see here the errors you should get when you turn up the warning/error level on the code you posted:

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AByJI3YnPijl6WYM

```
prog.cc:6:5: error: flexible array member 'a' in otherwise empty class is a GNU extension [-Werror,-Wgnu-empty-struct]
int a[][10];
    ^
prog.cc:6:5: error: flexible array members are a C99 feature [-Werror,-Wc99-extensions]
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Yes,the problem was coming due to array declaration only.Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I also am new to coding and not very familiar with C++, but I don't really see operator overloading going on in your code.  I just see two objects calling the same class functions.  The objects (I think) have the same values so yes the outputs would be the same.
Operator overloading would be like functions(int x) and then another
function(int x, int y).  Different arguments, same function name.

Comment: `test operator + (test t2)` is operator overloading.  You're talking about overloaded functions, not operators.

Comment: @rathi bond,u are getting confused b/w function overloading and operator overloading.This is the case of operator overloading.